# How do I use a grep output to sed and change a word to change a portion of the original text file

Tags: shell, sed, grep

A portion of my text file says:

```
callingNumber: xxxxxxx 
irrelevantnumberinfo: xxxxxxx
irrelevantnumberinfo2: xxxxxxx 
number: 12345678
```

I want the portion of my original textfile to look like:

```
callingNumber: xxxxxxx 
irrelevantnumbeRinfo: xxxxxxx
irrelevantnumbeRinfo2: xxxxxxx 
numbeR: 12345678
```

I've tried `cat test.txt | grep -A3 callingNumber | sed -i 's/number/numbeR/g'` but it keeps telling me that the there is no input file for sed.

Note that the original text file has more "number" words in it and I only want to change this particular portion.

Comment: sed is relying on the output of an earlier command, not with a file. Hence, you cannot use `-i`

Comment: @Guru but this does not allow it to edit the original file, how do you work around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i '/callingNumber/,+3{ s/number/numbeR/ }' file
```

Output to file:

```
callingNumber: xxxxxxx 
irrelevantnumbeRinfo: xxxxxxx
irrelevantnumbeRinfo2: xxxxxxx 
numbeR: 12345678
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `sed` alone with two expression using the normal `s/find/replace/` substitution, e.g.

```
$ sed 's/rinfo/Rinfo/;s/^number/numbeR/' file
callingNumber: xxxxxxx
irrelevantnumbeRinfo: xxxxxxx
irrelevantnumbeRinfo2: xxxxxxx
numbeR: 12345678
```

or with `grep`,

```
$ grep -A3 callingNumber file | sed 's/rinfo/Rinfo/;s/^number/numbeR/'
(same result)
```

or as you have it, without `-i` and you guarantee `number` won't appear anywhere you don't want to change, e.g. `grep -A3 callingNumber file | sed 's/number/numbeR/'`

---

**Editing In-Place with Range from Pattern and Next 3 Lines**

You can use `sed` with a range-expression to make the substitution and edit in place the next 3 lines after `callingNumber` with:

```
$ sed -i '/^callingNumber/,4s/number/numbeR/' file
```

---

**Changing 3-Lines After Every Occurrence of `callingNumber` with `awk`**

If you need to change the three lines after every occurrence of `callingNumber` then you can use `awk` and redirect to a new file and then replace the original file when done, e.g.

```
awk '/^callingNumber/{n=0} n<=3 {sub(/number/, "numbeR");n++}1' file > newfile \
mv -f newfile file
```

Comment: Would it matter if in my original file, the "callingNumber" is indented and has spaces after it? @David C. Rankin

Comment: Yes - - in that case you can remove the `'^'` anchor before `callingNumber` to match that anywhere in the line, or you can use `^[ \t]*callingNumber` to match any number of spaces and/or tabs before it.